# Scheduling periodic reactive tasks in Spring using cron?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cron, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Normally I would do something like this to schedule a job to be periodically executed in Spring with cron in a given timezone:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * *", zone = "Europe/Stockholm")
public void scheduleStuff() {
    // Do stuff
}
```

This is will block the thread calling `scheduleStuff` until the job is completed. However in this case the "stuff" I want to do is all implemented using Springs' non-blocking building blocks of [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) (i.e. `Mono`, `Flux` etc).

E.g. let's say that I want to trigger this function periodically:

```
Flux<Void> stuff() {
    return ..
}
```

I can of course simply call `stuff().subscribe()` (or even `stuff().block()`) but this will block the thread. Is there a better way to achieve the same things as `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * *", zone = "Europe/Stockholm")` for non-blocking code?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actualy, `subscribe()` doesn't block your thread. You could call `stuff().subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel()).subscribe()` or other scheduler to be sure that execution will be done in a separate thread, if you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more option:

```
public class PeriodicReactiveTasksInSpring implements SmartLifecycle {

    private final AtomicReference<Subscription> subscription;
    private final Long executionPeriod;

    public PeriodicReactiveTasksInSpring(Long executionPeriod) {
        this.subscription = new AtomicReference<>();
        this.executionPeriod = executionPeriod;
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        if (Objects.isNull(subscription.get())) {
            updateConfig()
                    .doOnSubscribe(sub -> {
                        subscription.set(sub);
                    }).subscribe();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        Optional.ofNullable(subscription.get())
                .ifPresent(sub -> {
                    sub.cancel();
                    subscription.set(null);
                });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRunning() {
        return Objects.nonNull(subscription.get());
    }


    private Flux<Item> updateConfig() {
        return Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(executionPeriod))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMap(cfg -> {
                    // Do your job here
                })
                .onErrorContinue((err, msg) -> LOGGER.error("Error: {} message: {}", err, msg));
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap the `stuff` method in an async method

Ex:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 10 * * *", zone = "Europe/Stockholm")
public void scheduleStuff() {
    stuffService.doStuffAsync();
}
```

Service with async method

```
public class StuffService() implements IStuffService {

    @Async
    public void doStuffAsync() {
       // Call and subscribe to your flux method here
    }

}
```

The call to `doStuffAsync()` will return immediately the the `scheduleStuff`therefor not blocking the thread.

Comment: @BrianClozel I'm not following your logic. `doStuffAsync()` would call and subscribe to the `stuff()` method. This is the same thing that the accepted answer recommended.